# How to show/hide special folders in home directory nautilus

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, home-directory

In **nautilus** home folder shows some special folders like:  **Music,Documents,Pictures** etc.

Most of the time I am not interested in browsing these directories.

Is there any way to toggle the visibility of these type of folders in home directory? Is it possible to show files and folders in groups(Like in Window Vista).

Note that this is not same as [this question](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1679009).